# APEX Class Name NOT LIKE

Tags: apex

I can only find examples of soql queries in other questions so they do not answer what I need. I want to write a class to fire when a attachment is added to an Opportunity we query all the attachments and put that number on the Opportunity.

So I want to pass a map into the method I want to filter the records so that only ones related to an opportunity and do not have invoice in the name. The problem is I can't seem to figure out what the right syntax is for the if statement.

Example:

```
public static void updateHasAttachment(Map<Id, Attachment> singleMap)
{
    Map<Id, Opportunity> rollup = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    for(Attachment record : singleMap.values()) 
    {
        if(
            record.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType &&
            (NOT record.Name LIKE \'%INVOICE%'\)
        )
        {
            rollup.put(record.ParentId, null);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong as it will not compile in different variations I've tried on the LIKE line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using LIKE in Apex code. LIKE is only applicable to SOQL queries.

I have edited your code and you can try this now.

```
public static void updateHasAttachment(Map<Id, Attachment> singleMap)
{
    Map<Id, Opportunity> rollup = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    for(Attachment record : singleMap.values()) 
    {
        if( !record.Name.contains('INVOICE')  && record.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType  )
        {
            rollup.put(record.ParentId, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In apex, that `Name` property on the sobject is a string and as such, you should use the [String methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) on it.

```
record.Name.contains('INVOICE')
```

This method returns true when the substring `INVOICE` is found in the `Name` property value.

Comment: ... or containsIgnoreCase if needed.

Comment: Ohhh, so there doesn't seem to be a doesnotcontains string method so would it need a ! in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

why not query all attachments with:

```
List<Attachment> attachments = [ Select Id, Name, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE NOT( Name LIKE '%INVOICE%' ) ORDER By ParentId ];
```

then just map like

```
Map<Id, List<Attachment>> attachmentsMap = new Map<Id, List<Attachment>>();

for( Attachment att : attachments ){

   if( attachmentsMap.containsKey( att.ParentId )){ 
        List<Attachment> atts = attachmentsMap.get( att.ParentId );
        atts.add( att );
        attachmentsMap.put( att.ParentId, atts );
   }
   else {
       List<Attachment> atts = new List<Attachment>{ att };
       attachmentsMap.put( att.ParentId, atts );
   }
}
```

Then when you need to retrieve the items for the opportunity :

```
 if( attachmentsMap.containsKey( opp.Id )){
    opp.Number_Attachments__c  = attachmentsMap.get( opp.Id ).size();
 }
 else {
    opp.Number_Attachments__c = null;
 }
```

I am unsure what you are trying to map out given your map in your method above - but your description to me makes me think that you're looking to update the Opportunity with just a count of Attachments that are related to that specific Opportunity.

so a quick rewrite of your trigger - would easily be to gather all of the Id values related to trigger.new in your opportunity trigger and query all attachments like this:

```
 Set<Id> opps = new Set<Id>();
for( Opportunity opp : Trigger.new ){
    opps.add( opp.Id );
}

List<Attachment> attachments = [ Select Id, Name, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE  Id IN: opps AND ( NOT( Name LIKE '%Invoice%' )) ORDER BY ParentId ];
```

Then map these by parentId - pull the list out of the map in whatever step of your trigger and use the list size as needed. Doing this up front would help to keep this able to bulkified for those mass updates.